# Java hashmap syntax confusion

Tags: java, hashmap

the code below is counting character.  I am a bit new to hashmaps so I am confused about the syntax and what's it doing from this line: Map charCounter = new TreeMap();  Can someone please dumb this code down and explain from that line please?

```
    public class repeated {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Abaa";

        char[] char_array = str.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("The Given String is : " + str);

    Map<Character, Integer> charCounter = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (char x : char_array) {

    charCounter.put(x,charCounter.get(x) == null ? 1 : charCounter.get(x) + 1);

        }

    for (Character key : charCounter.keySet()) {
  System.out.println("occurrence of '" + key + "' is  "+ charCounter.get(key));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can't see `HashMap` as title said !!!!

Comment: +1 Wundwin Born. HashMap and TreeMap are completely different in terms of behaviour and performances and don't fit to the same use cases. Go check the doc for further information, making good using of the Java Collection API is important.

Comment: i think you are talking about treemap. it's a map implementation as bst.

Comment: How do you write this using hashmaps then?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr `TreeMap` is not a simple Binary Search Tree, it's a Red Black Tree.

Comment: `new HashMap<>()` instead of `new TreeMap<>()`. Simple as that !

Answer (score 0):

[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is one of the classes that implement the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. Therefore you can assign an instance of `TreeMap` to a variable whose type is `Map`.

The line `charCounter.put(x,charCounter.get(x) == null ? 1 : charCounter.get(x) + 1)` searches the `char` `x` in the `Map`. If it's not found, it adds it as a key to the map with value of `1`. If it's found it gets its current value from the `Map` and increases it by one.

This means this `Map` counts how many times each character appears in the input `String`.